# How can I create a new column on a Pandas Dataframe with conditions based on previous and next row?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I am trying to create a new Pandas column that indicates whether a number is the largest compared to the row above and the row below.

The column is going to be binary, where '1' indicates it is the highest number compared to last and next row, and '0' will indicate the condition is not satisfied.

This is how the data looks:

```
           Date      High
    0   2015-11-11  25.90
    1   2015-11-12  27.12
    2   2015-11-13  26.20
    3   2015-11-16  26.19
    4   2015-11-17  25.51
    5   2015-11-18  26.31
    6   2015-11-19  26.00
    7   2015-11-20  27.01
    8   2015-11-23  25.60
    9   2015-11-24  27.00
    10  2015-11-25  26.49
```

This is my desired outcome:

```
    Date        High    higher
0   2015-11-11  25.90   0.0
1   2015-11-12  27.12   1.0
2   2015-11-13  26.20   0.0
3   2015-11-16  26.19   0.0
4   2015-11-17  25.51   0.0
5   2015-11-18  26.31   1.0
6   2015-11-19  26.00   0.0
7   2015-11-20  27.01   1.0
8   2015-11-23  25.60   0.0
9   2015-11-24  27.00   1.0
10  2015-11-25  26.49   0.0
```

For further illustration, here is what I did on Microsoft Excel, which is exactly what I am trying to achieve with Python:
[ExcelExample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I65Ot.png)

**First Attempt:**

```
for i in dftest['High']:
    if dftest['High'][i] > dftest['High'][i-1] and dftest['High'][i] > dftest['High'][i+1]:
        dftest['higher'] = 1
    else:
        dftest['higher'] = 0
```

This results in the error:
*"TypeError: cannot do label indexing on class 'pandas.core.indexes.range.RangeIndex' with these indexers [25.9] of class 'float'"*

**Second Attempt:**
Here I try to make use of '.shift()'.

```
for i in dftest['High']:
    if dftest['High'] > dftest['High'].shift(1) and dftest['High'] > dftest['High'].shift(-1):
        dftest['higher'] = 1
    else:
        dftest['higher'] = 0
```

This results in error:
*"TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'float' and 'float'"*

**Third Attempt (similar to the second attempt):**
Used '&' operator instead of 'and'.

Results in error:
*"TypeError: cannot do label indexing on class 'pandas.core.indexes.range.RangeIndex' with these indexers [25.9] of class 'float'"*

Would appreciate any sort of help!

Edit: I would really appreciate if the solution provided could easily be alternated if I wanted to find the highest of 5 or 7 or 9 consecutive numbers. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

You can use .pct_change() to see if values are increasing or decreasing, and then use np.where() to replace values on condition.

```
df = pd.read_clipboard()
df['higher'] = df['High'].pct_change()
df['higher'] = np.where(df['higher'] > 0, 1.0, 0.0)

print(df)


    Date        High    higher
0   2015-11-11  25.90   0.0
1   2015-11-12  27.12   1.0
2   2015-11-13  26.20   0.0
3   2015-11-16  26.19   0.0
4   2015-11-17  25.51   0.0
5   2015-11-18  26.31   1.0
6   2015-11-19  26.00   0.0
7   2015-11-20  27.01   1.0
8   2015-11-23  25.60   0.0
9   2015-11-24  27.00   1.0
10  2015-11-25  26.49   0.0
```

For your comment, you can do rolling max.

```
df['rolling_max'] = df['High'].rolling(5, min_periods=1).max()

print(df)

Date    High    higher  rolling_max
0   2015-11-11  25.90   0.0 25.90
1   2015-11-12  27.12   0.0 27.12
2   2015-11-13  26.20   0.0 27.12
3   2015-11-16  26.19   0.0 27.12
4   2015-11-17  25.51   0.0 27.12
5   2015-11-18  26.31   1.0 27.12
6   2015-11-19  26.00   0.0 26.31
7   2015-11-20  27.01   1.0 27.01
8   2015-11-23  25.60   0.0 27.01
9   2015-11-24  27.00   1.0 27.01
10  2015-11-25  26.49   1.0 27.01
```

Comment: I edited my response to match your example col names.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response! How would I go about it if I wanted to find the highest of 5 (2 numbers below and 2 above), 7 (3 numbers below and 3 above), or 9 consecutive numbers?

Comment: The rolling max was a really good idea, but when checking my data, there was a lack of consistency. I've posted an answer and would really appreciate for you to review it :)

Comment: What do you mean by "inconsistent?" IIUC rolling().max() is designed for what you want. You might have to play around with the parameters a bit to meet your specific needs. However, this post now has multiple questions in it. I'd recommend cleaning this one up and asking a new question.

Answer (score 1):

This so called local max

```
from scipy.signal import argrelextrema
ary=argrelextrema(df.High.values,np.greater)
df['local max']=np.where(df.index.isin(ary[0]),1,0)
df
          Date   High  local max
0   2015-11-11  25.90          0
1   2015-11-12  27.12          1
2   2015-11-13  26.20          0
3   2015-11-16  26.19          0
4   2015-11-17  25.51          0
5   2015-11-18  26.31          1
6   2015-11-19  26.00          0
7   2015-11-20  27.01          1
8   2015-11-23  25.60          0
9   2015-11-24  27.00          1
10  2015-11-25  26.49          0
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the response! How would I go about it if I wanted to find the highest of 5 (2 numbers below and 2 above), 7 (3 numbers below and 3 above), or 9 consecutive numbers?

Comment: @Ibs that is different , you may need to check the logic and write your own function then

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I decided to use this:

```
hf_three = []

try:
    for i in df.index:   
        if df.loc[i]['High']>df.loc[i+1]['High'] and df.loc[i]['High']>df.loc[i-1]['High']:
            hf_three.append(1)
        else:
            hf_three.append(0)
except ValueError:              # To handle cases where 'i-1' doesn't exist.
    hf_three.append(0)
except KeyError:                # To handle cases where 'i+1' doesn't exist
    hf_three.append(0)

df['higher'] = hf_three
```

Though this works, if I replace '>' for '<', it no longer works and will not even append. Solutions to this will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
df1.assign(higher=df1.High.rolling(3,min_periods=3,center=True).max().eq(df1.High).astype(int))

    Date        High    higher
0   2015-11-11  25.90   0.0
1   2015-11-12  27.12   1.0
2   2015-11-13  26.20   0.0
3   2015-11-16  26.19   0.0
4   2015-11-17  25.51   0.0
5   2015-11-18  26.31   1.0
6   2015-11-19  26.00   0.0
7   2015-11-20  27.01   1.0
8   2015-11-23  25.60   0.0
9   2015-11-24  27.00   1.0
10  2015-11-25  26.49   0.0
```